# SQL Server rolling average

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, rolling-average

```
select
    Date, [Close],
    avg([close]) over (order by date asc rows 4 preceding) as MA10
from 
    dbo.APPL
```

This query returns the rolling 4 day average of stock prices. However I want to show the values as `NULL` if preceding days are fewer than 4.

How do I adjust that in SQL Server?

Comment: Can't you just to count([close]) over the same partition and use that to find if there are fewer than 4 rows returned?

Comment: I can do that, but how do I select only those rows where count>3

Comment: I assume you can do that with a having clause on the count.  Or by wrapping the field itself in an if / then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think JeffUK meant doing something like this:

```
select
    Date, [Close],
    case when days >= 4 then MA10 end as MA10
from
(
    select
        Date, [Close],
        avg([close]) over (order by date asc rows 4 preceding) as MA10,
        count([close]) over (order by date asc rows 4 preceding) as days
    from 
        dbo.APPL

) X
```